What did they mean with "saiyajins remain young their whole life"?
As far as we knew, in Dragon Ball Z we were told (by Vegeta if I recall correctly) that saiyajin remains young more time to last more in the battle. But now in Dragon Ball Daima (at least in the spanish version I'm watching) we are told that "saiyajins remain young their whole life" . This could be interpreted like saiyajins never die of age. Is this really what they said in the japanese version?
What did they mean with "saiyajins remain young their whole life"?

I'm not sure (hence comment rather than answer), but my interpretation is that they remain physically young and healthy most of their life.  I.e., maybe they age up to 25 or so, and then don't seem to age further until they get really old.

Wiki https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Saiyan#Aging,_lifespan_and_growth has some references on the subject (which I can't really check, not even in English). The Dazenshuu (published 1995) apparently indicates that they do have a finite lifespan, ideally similar to the human one. Toriyama has also said that they are naturally longer-lived. In DBS chapter 7 a statement along the lines of Sayajins being still in their prime until the age of 80 is attributed to Vegeta.

Although probably the only old Sayajin ever shown was 100something-year-old Pan at the end of GT.

It should just mean they look young for the entirety of their finite life, and I don't think you have to take it too literally.
